# The numbers count only once, instead of infinitely

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I'm creating an interval timer. I want the number to count down to 0 after entering the number and pressing the button, if it already counts down to 0 then the function starts from the beginning. In my code fukncja counts down to 0, but the next countdown doesn't end with 0, but it counts down to minus numbers. Why doesn't it work? Can you help?

```
var workI = 0;
var countDownI = 0;
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',function(){
  var workValue = Math.ceil(document.getElementById('work-seconds').value);
  if(!workI)clearInterval(workI);
  function countDown(){
    var workSec = new Date().getTime() + workValue * 1000;
    countWorkSec();
    workI = setInterval(countWorkSec,1000);
    function countWorkSec(){
      var countSec = Math.ceil((workSec - new Date().getTime()) / 1000);
      countSec < 10 ? document.getElementById('workSecs').textContent = "0" + countSec : document.getElementById('workSecs').textContent = countSec;
      if(countSec == 0){
        clearInterval(workI);
        workI = 0;
      }
    };
  }
  countDown();
  countDownI = setInterval(countDown,workValue * 1000);
});
```

```
<p>Work</p>
<input type="number" id="work-seconds" placeholder="seconds" min="0">
<br>
<br>
<button id="btn">START</button>
<p>Work Timer : <span id="workSecs"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var workI = 0;
var countDownI = 0;
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',function(){
  var workValue = Math.ceil(document.getElementById('work-seconds').value);
  function countDown(){
    if(workI)clearInterval(workI); // Change - Clearinterval when countDown starts
    var workSec = new Date().getTime() + workValue * 1000;
    countWorkSec();
    workI = setInterval(countWorkSec,1000);
    function countWorkSec(){
      var countSec = Math.ceil((workSec - new Date().getTime()) / 1000);
      countSec < 10 ? document.getElementById('workSecs').textContent = "0" + countSec : document.getElementById('workSecs').textContent = countSec;
      if(countSec == 0){
        clearInterval(workI);
        workI = 0;
      }
    };
  }
  countDown();
  countDownI = setInterval(countDown, (workValue + 1) * 1000);
});
```